# Writing to file in iOS using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, ios, file-io

Is it possible to create a text file using C/C++ calls in iOS? Is it then possible to open and read the file from outside the application? That is, application A creates a text file somewhere it has permissions to write to and application B then reads from it. Or, forget application B, can I just open it and read?

Comment: What do you want to write ? Objective-C objects ?

Comment: Simple `printf` statements to print text messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Use `NSFileHandle` to get read/write access to files and `NSFileManager` to create directories and list their contents and do all other sorts of file system access.

Just keep in mind that every App is sandboxed and can only write to its own designated directories. You can get the path to these directories with code like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
```

However, you can *not* access files of another App.

iTunes automatically backs up these directories, so they are automatically restored if the user does a device restore. Also keep in mind that you should not "expose" the file system to the App users in form of file-browsers or "save dialogs", etc.

Comment: I know how to do this in Obj-C. I want to use C/C++ calls only. I have heard it is possible but don't know how. Also, I will want to read that file manually later, so, I will have to access it from outside the app.

Comment: In this case you can use the standard C functions like *fopen()*. However, this is way less convenient than using the higher-level API. The only way to "make the file available later" is to place them into the App's *Documents* directory and configure the bundle.plist correctly so these files can be added/removed using iTunes' file manager.

Comment: Great! But how do I get the documents directory using only C calls?

Comment: I doubt you can do that easily. The UUID in the App's path is random and there is no "plain C" variant of the NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains method for getting the paths. Why can't you use the higher level APIs if I may ask?

Comment: It's a legacy project. The point where I want to create the file is in a cpp file which, afaik, can't contain Obj-C code.

Comment: You *can* mix C++ and Objective-C. AFAIK you just have to change the file suffix to ".mm" so that Xcode knows how to call the compiler correctly. Just make sure you have an actual UIApplication running (with an AutoreleasePool), otherwise you might get some problems.

Comment: This answer worked for me. I created the file in applications document directory by fetching the directory using the above code.

Answer (score 25):

Since the question is explicitly asking for C/C++ and NOT Obj-C, I'm adding this answer, which I saw [here](http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=829) and might help someone:

```
char buffer[256];

//HOME is the home directory of your application
//points to the root of your sandbox
strcpy(buffer,getenv("HOME"));

//concatenating the path string returned from HOME
strcat(buffer,"/Documents/myfile.txt");

//Creates an empty file for writing
FILE *f = fopen(buffer,"w");

//Writing something
fprintf(f, "%s %s %d", "Hello", "World", 2016);

//Closing the file
fclose(f);
```

Using this C code:

```
buffer = "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6DA355FB-CA4B-4627-A23C-B1B36980947A/Documents/myfile.txt"
```

While the Obj-C version:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

is returning

```
documentsDirectory = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6DA355FB-CA4B-4627-A23C-B1B36980947A/Documents
```

FYI, in case you noticed about the "private" small difference, I wrote to both places and they happened to be the same.

Comment: Where would I find the file using the Files app or iTunes/Xcode then?

Comment: I couldn't find the files after saving it. I'm pretty sure I did the exactly what you show with C, but couldn't find it when connected to  a Mac.