# iOS: Writing file to Documents folder using C/C++ and retrieve it easily with Files/iTunes or thirdparty tools

Tags: ios, c, io, local-storage

I've consulted this question:

[Writing to file in iOS using C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341919/writing-to-file-in-ios-using-c-c/39022407#39022407)

and its answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39022407/987846

I seemed to have written files onto the disk, i.e., all the file opening and writing finished. But when I expect to see the files written to disk appear in the Files.app on iOS or iTunes on macOS, I found none there. In particular, my app doesn't appear in the iTunes's File Sharing category.

I've also tried thirdparty tools such as:

https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy

calling its file downloading command gives me an empty folder

```
./ios-deploy --download=/Documents --bundle_id com.mycompany.myapp -2 dest_dir
```

So how should I retrieve that file after closing the app?

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out myself.

I needed to add a target property to my `Info.plist`, by typing in a new row:

```
UIFileSharingEnabled
```

or simply select from the property list

```
Application supports iTunes file sharing
```

Make the value `YES`.
Then my app will show up in iTunes `File Sharing` category.
The file saved into Documents folder will appear there.

For completeness, below is ObjC/C code snippets that can be inserted into an ObjC-based project.

```c
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.ext"];
    const char* filePath = [file UTF8String];
    FILE* pFile = NULL;
    pFile = fopen(filePath, "ab");
    float data = 9.9f;
    fwrite(&data, sizeof(float), 1, pFile);    
    fclose(pFile);
}
```